# Get items from next week

Tags: mysql, sql, date, query-optimization, where-clause

I was starting to do a query such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE (weekofyear(now())+1) <= date_inserted < weekofyear(now()+2)
```

The problem with this is that items from previous years will also show up here. What would be the best way to do this query -- I'm hoping I can still use an index on the query on the `date_inserted` field, which is why I'm asking this here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase this as:

```
where
        date_inserted >=  current_date + interval 7 - weekday(current_date) day
    and date_inserted <  current_date + interval 14 - weekday(current_date) day
```

Expression `current_date + interval 7 - weekday(current_date) day` gives you the first day of next week. This works under the assumptions that your weeks start on Monday.

You can see that no date function is applied on the `date_inserted` column, which mean that MySQL would happily use an index on that column for filtering, if any.